# Continuity of real functions

Tags: set-theory, forcing, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The following question concerns that without $ZF+DC$, can every function be  "a little bit" continuous?

> **Question** Is it consistent with $ZF+DC$ that for any function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ and any positive measure set $A$, there is a positive measure closed set $B\subseteq A$ so that $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed?

How about in Solovay's model?

Comment: One has no Lebesgue measure in ZF alone---after all, with ZF the reals can be a countable union of countable sets. So if you are referring to measure in a ZF context, you have to say a bit more for it to be sensible. Perhaps you want to work in ZF+DC?

Comment: You are right. I should say $ZF+DC$.

Comment: In Solovay's model where all functions are Lebesgue measurable, this should be a consequence of Lusin's theorem.

Comment: I am not sure whether it can be deduced from Lusin's theorem, unless you assume the function has Lusin's (N) property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any Borel $f:[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ satisfying $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is dense in $[0, 1]$ for every $y \in [0, 1]$ is a counterexample. For example, $f(x) = \limsup_n \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n}$ where $x = 0.x_1 x_2 \dots$ is the binary expansion of $x$.

Comment: Nice example, thanks!